# How to model a Railway ballast bed/rocks?

Tags: mesh, particles

I'm very new to Blender, and I've been trying to recreate a model similar to this:
[image]

So far i've tried my way with setting up particles based on some simple rocks I created and added as collection, but the rocks intersect and it basically look bad.
I've also tried with some rigid body simulation to fill up a shape, but this also doesn't really seem to do the trick.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you please attach the screeshot directly in your question? Use the Edit button and the add Image function. This way the link won't expire or disappear...

Comment: Did you try just modeling the basic shape of the bed and use Emitter particle system for the rocks?

Comment: Without knowing what the [purpose](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/could-we-brush-up-the-help-center-please) of your model is, I try a shot in the dark here: Creating all those rocks by whatever means is going to be pretty darn demanding on your hardware, so I'd suggest trying [Microdisplacement](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dRzzaRvVDng)

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The purpose of the model is for now just a static render as seen in the question. 
I did try creating the basic shape and use emitter particles, both with volume and faces, but this is when the stones intersect too much. Can you help me how to set it up to look good?

Microdisplacement seems smart, but I don't see how that solves the problem.